# Alphabetical sort in postgresql using indexes.

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing

I have a table with more than 100000 rows and i want to sort them alphabetically using surname and name . I want to achieve the sort by using an index . I've tried this :

```
CREATE INDEX idx0 ON "People"(surname,name DESC NULLS LAST);
```

But the table is not sorted correctly . What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The index will speed up searches and order by. However, it will not re-order the physical table. I.e you still have to add an `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: Tables represent *unordered* sets.  If you want results in a particular order, you need to use `order by` on a query.

Comment: are you looking for `CLUSTER` command? keep in mind it is one time operation - later rows will unsort again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to select data from table in this order, you should execute a query:

```
SELECT * FROM People ORDER BY surname, name DESC NULLS LAST
```

This query will run fast, because database will use index instead of sorting data on the fly (note, that it works only if columns and sorting directions of query's ORDER BY matches exactly with columns and sorting directions of index).

If you want to reorder data in table physically, then you can execute:

```
CLUSTER People USING idx0
```

But keep in mind that `CLUSTER` command will only reorder existing data. If you insert new data into table, it will not be placed in desired order, so you will have to execute `CLUSTER` command again.